# How compute exponential matrix's determinant but don't compute exponential?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Example. $$A = \left( \begin{matrix}1 &0 &3\\
>                               -1 &2 &0\\
>                               0 &1 &-1\end{matrix}\right)$$
> We want to compute $\det(e^A)$ but don't compute exponential matrix $e^A$.
> My idea is use Jordan standard type i.e. exist $P$ s.t. $A = PJP^{-1}$ ,so $|e^A| = |e^J|$,we just compute $e^J$.In this case ,I think $J$ is a diagnonal matrix.So we first compute it's eigenvalue.But my problem are there.
> $|\lambda E-A|=\lambda^3-2\lambda^2-\lambda+5$,I clould not find eigenvalue from this equation.
> So my think we whethere can't compute eigenvalue or just solve above equation?
> Can you help me?Thanks.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Properties).

Comment: @Trivial: you can search for "trace identity " for any complex matrix which holds $det(e^A)=e^{trace(A)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $\det(e^A)=e^{\text{tr}(A)}$ (can you see why? try verifying this on a diagonal matrix)

The trace can easily be found as the sum of the diagonal entries of $A$.

...

As an aside, even if you can't easily solve the cubic characteristic equation for all the eigenvalues separately (or are unwilling/unable to use the [Cubic Formula](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/)), then the product of all roots of an $n$th degree polynomial can be found as $-1^n$ times the constant term, which can give you the determinant easily!

Comment: oh!Thanks,I have known it .I just I remember the formula wrong.